# SQL Group By min value usable as a variable?

Tags: sql

I have the following table ComponentsB:

```
CID Name    PPP ProcessingCharge    LName   Typ
1   RadXL   10  5   EisenAG Rad
2   RadXL   15  0   LederGmbH   Rad
3   RadL    10  2   LederGmbH   Rad
4   RadXL   2   1   RadAG   Rad
5   RadXL   4   10  sdfkj   Rad
6   SchraubeM   1   2   EisenAG Schraube
7   ZangeS  3   11  EisenAG Zange
8   ZangeM  12  12  sdfkj   Zange
```

I want to get for every "Name" the lowest "ProcessingCharge" with the corresponding LName

```
select Name, min(ProcessingCharge)
from ComponentsB
group by Name
```

works perfectly fine but I can't get the corresponding LName because I get the error that it is not part of the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of this query as an aggregation query.  Think of it as a filtering query.  You want the row for each `Name` that has the minimum charge:

```
select c.*
from ComponentsB c
where c.ProcessingCharge = (select min(c2.ProcessingCharge)
                            from ComponentsB c2
                            where c2.Name = c.Name
                           );
```